# how to get the attributes from xml file?

Tags: java, xml, dom

My Xml File looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pointList SYSTEM "point.dtd">
<pointList>
<point unit="mm">
<x>2</x>
<y>3</y>
</point>

<point unit="cm">
<x>9</x>
<y>3</y>
</point>

<point unit="px">
<x>4</x>
<y>7</y>
</point>

</pointList>
```

When i try to get attributes of tag point:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class TryXml {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        File f = new File("p1.xml");
        try {
            doc=builder.parse(f);
        }
        catch (SAXException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println(root.getTagName());

        System.out.println("****************");


        NodeList nList = root.getChildNodes();
        for (int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++) {
        if(nList.item(i) instanceof Element)

        System.out.println(nList.item(i).getAttributes());
    }

    }
    }
```

all i get is something like the address:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttributeMap@3214512e
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttributeMap@53ddbcb1
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.AttributeMap@28f337b
```

can anyone give me a hint on how to get the attributes of point and maybe other inner tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your println with the following:

```
System.out.println(((Element) nList.item(i)).getAttribute("unit"));
```

This should give you the "unit" attribute of the current element.

Comment: But if i use "unit" how do i get the values of inner tags? i need the result to look like this: `point 23mm, point 93cm, point 47px`

Comment: You now have the `Element` and can from there work your way through the childs: `((Element) nList.item(i)).getChildNodes()` will give you another `NodeList` through which you can iterate exactly as you did through `nList` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

"Element root = doc.getElementByTagName("pointList"); "

instead of,

"Element root = doc.getDocumentElement(); "

Answer (score 0):

[`Element.getAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getAttributes%28%29) will give a list of all attributes in that `Element`. If you know beforehand the name of the attribute and just want to get its value, use [`Element.getAttribute(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

If you need to get the child elements, use [`Element.getChildNodes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes%28%29). To get the text inside an `Element`, or more specifically a `Node`, use [`getNodeValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue%28%29).

For instance:

```
        NodeList nList = root.getChildNodes();
        String out = "";
        for (int i=0;i<nList.getLength();i++) {
            // Assuming all first-level tags are <point>
            Element point = (Element) nList.item(i);
            String unit = point.getAttribute("unit");
            out += "point ";
            for (int y=0;y<point.getChildNodes().getLength();y++){
                Node child = point.getChildNodes().item(y);
                // String nodeName = child.getNodeName();
                String nodeValue = child.getNodeValue();
                out += nodeValue;
            }
        out += unit;
        out += ", ";
        }
```

Will output `point 23mm, point 93cm, point 47px,`.

Comment: What do i put in System.out.println()?? and where in the code should i place it? and also ` Element point = (Element) nList.item(i);
` says that cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element

Answer (score 0):

this post [getting xml attribute with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927385/get-the-the-attributes-from-an-xml-file-using-java) does what you are trying to achieve. It teaches regular xml parsing and manipulation. It also retrieves attribute.

Good luck!