# Unable to get Name attribute of Childnode

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I have a XML file that looks like this:

```
<exist:result xmlns:exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist">
<exist:collection name="/db/RCM" created="2013-03-24T09:37:34.957+05:30" owner="admin" group="dba" permissions="rwxrwxrwx">
<exist:resource name="demo2.xml" created="2013-03-24T09:44:13.696+05:30" last-modified="2013-03-24T09:44:13.696+05:30" owner="guest" group="guest" permissions="rw-r--r--"/>
<exist:resource name="demo3.xml" created="2013-03-24T09:45:47.592+05:30" last-modified="2013-03-24T09:45:47.592+05:30" owner="guest" group="guest" permissions="rw-r--r--"/>
<exist:resource name="rcmdemo.xml" created="2013-03-25T11:36:45.659+05:30" last-modified="2013-03-25T11:36:45.659+05:30" owner="guest" group="guest" permissions="rw-r--r--"/>
<exist:resource name="rcmdemo2.xml" created="2013-03-25T11:47:03.564+05:30" last-modified="2013-03-25T11:47:03.564+05:30" owner="guest" group="guest" permissions="rw-r--r--"/>
</exist:collection>
</exist:result>
```

I want to fetch the name of the XML files, so the output looks like this:

```
demo2.xml
demo3.xml
rcmdemo.xml
rcmdemo2.xml
```

I have written the following code:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("exist:resource");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = nodeList.item(i);
    Node actualNode = n.getFirstChild();
    if (actualNode != null) {
        System.out.println(actualNode.getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

But it does not return the output that I want, where am I going wrong?

Comment: I dont think name is a childnode , check for attributes of a given node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the attribute from the given node since your `name` is an attribute of `exist:resource`.

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("exist:resource");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = nodeList.item(i);
            Node actualNode = n.getFirstChild();
            if (actualNode != null) {
                // Will return node value
                System.out.println(actualNode.getNodeValue());
                // Will return the attribute value
                System.out.println(current.getAttributeValue("name")); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In this example name is an attribute of the node rather than the name of the node. Please look at the following question for information regarding attributes of nodes, the second answer in particular is what you are looking for i think.

[get the the attributes from an XML File using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927385/get-the-the-attributes-from-an-xml-file-using-java?rq=1)